# Mongoose error/NodeJS when multiple queries are used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to use two queries inside the post request, because I'd like to push one thing to an array upon satisfying a certain condition, and push again to the array upon satisfying a different condition. However, Node.JS crashes whenever I try to add the second User.find.

```
router.post('/route', function(req, res){
    arr = []; //Empty array each time button is clicked before executing functions

User.find({"propertyA":req.user.valueA, "propertyB": req.user.valueB}, function(err, users) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //Push to array 3 times
            req.user.arr.push(users[i].username);
            req.user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        };
    };
    if (err) throw err;
});

User.find({"propertyC": req.user.valueC}, function(err, users) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            req.user.arr.push(users[i].username);
            req.user.arr.save(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        };
    };
    if (err) throw err;
});

res.redirect('/users/examplepage');
```

});

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error at model.wrappedPointCut [as save]

Comment: why dont you create and array using forloop and push at one using model.udpate({condition}, {$push : array})

Answer (score 0):

In your second request, you do:

```
req.user.arr.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

I think `req.user.arr` is not a Mongoose model, but just a plain `array`. Thus, invoking the `.save()` function on it will result in an error. You perhaps wanted to do `req.user.save()`.

Comment: Arr is defined in my schema for User: arr: [{type: String}]

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean you can call `.save()` on every property of your schema: this method is only defined on your document, hence an instance of your Model.